# What's the purpose of JUNOS' sfid process?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex

In the last few days, one Juniper EX-2200-48P has started complaining via syslog:

```
Jun 21 12:50:03 ex2200-b sfid[717]:
TASK_OS_MEMHIGH: Using 52118 KB of memory, 103 percent of available
```

After a visit on Juniper's website and search engine kung-fu, it appears I cannot find anything that states clearly what `sfid` takes care of.

Thus, I have two questions:

1. What is the purpose of that `sfid` process?
2. Is the above memory situation problematic and if so, can I safely restart it without impact?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `sfid` process is the `software forwarding infrastructure daemon`. This process handles all traffic that the switch cannot handle in hardware alone. Common examples of such traffic are:

- GRE encapsulation
- ARP resolution
- management traffic

High CPU usage for the `sfid` process might indicate a problem, and certainly could impact performance when you have legitimate traffic that ought to be software switched. I would suggest checking what traffic causes this problem in the first place.

Comment: You mentioned CPU in your answer, but he was pointing out the memory utilization was the concern

Comment: I don't know enough about the inner workings of JunOS to explain the memory use, but in this case I would suspect a memory-leak bug. Restarting the process should help, but beware that this will impact software-switched traffic. Or upgrade the software to a newer version and hope the bug is gone.